# Restrict some administrators from using WebDeploy

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, webdeploy

We have moved our .NET web app deployment to Microsoft WebDeploy 3.0, and the transition has gone really well.

We are able to quickly and simply deploy to dev, test, and soon, production. But we'd like to add an extra level of restriction for deployment to production. Partially for security, but mostly to avoid "oops, no I didn't." moments.

The user accounts that deploy to dev and test are domain admins. Is there a way to restrict who has access to connect to the WebDeploy service or who can publish? I'd like to remove Domain Admins from production WebDeploy, and add a deployment account used exclusively for this. But Domain Admins will still need pretty liberal access to the server, I'd just like to restrict them in WebDeploy.

[This seems to be a different question than most are asking, which is how to allow addtional, non-admin users access. I'd like to know how to **disallow** admins access.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have tagged with iis 7.5 I am assuming you are on IIS7. In that case you can use WMSvc service on the server for the deployment. [Web Management Service]. This service uses delegation to allow or disallow users. This is how web deployment works in a hosted environment.

You can by default give every dev access to a particular site or app under a site and give read only access to some. You can still have super user permissions to the admins by enabling a setting called dont apply delegation rules for admins. Here is an article that gives detailed description about this can be acheived.

http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler

Comment: I haven't had time to test or implement this, but accepting anyway: some day I'll implement this and hopefully will remember to come back here with my results.